# How to compile with OpenMP in Qt on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang, openmp

I'm trying to introduce some OMP parallelization into my C++ Qt application and I'm failing to compile it under macOS. Colleagues are using Windows or Linux and everything is working fine for them. What do I need to write in Qt's .pro-file and do in my system?

None of the similar questions on this or any other site solved my problem.
I'm usually compiling with Apple-provided clang, but there seems to be no OMP-support for that. So I've installed clang with llvm via homebrew, set up my kit in Qt accordingly and also tried every permutation of following lines in my .pro-file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
QMAKE_LINK = /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0/bin/clang-9
QMAKE_CC = /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0/bin/clang-9
QMAKE_CXX = /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0/bin/clang-9
LIBS += -fopenmp
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/
```

With all of that I get many weird problems leading to `symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`, also without any of the lines pointing to clang-9, but still this is the best I could achieve.
Without the last line I get `library not found for -lomp`, without the QMAKE_LINK line `unsupported option '-fopenmp'`.

None of the possible solutions I found online for these error messages helped either.
`libomp.dylib` is installed and linked into `/usr/local/lib`.
I also tried the whole process with GCC, but without success as well.

This is bugging me for three days already and I really hope this can be solved. Can't be that hard, can it? A solution that isn't messing with the compatibility on Windows/Linux would be optimal.

PS: I'm using qmake via the play button in Qt creator.

Reference:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179370/qt-creator-compiler-in-kit-for-project-is-being-ignored), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra-mojave), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579856/ld-library-not-found-for-lomp), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971394/brew-install-clang-omp-not-working) and many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppleClang should work just fine. Be sure to call the preprocessor to handle OMP via the `.pro`file.

```
macx: {
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -lomp -I/usr/local/include
}

macx: {
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lomp
}

macx: {
LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem! Unfortunately I have not enough reputation to give you an upvote, but I marked your answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet! no prob.