# build Qt project with openmp on macOS

Tags: macos, qt, openmp

I have a qmake project developed on windows that uses openmp and I want to build it on macOS. I followed this instruction [How to compile with OpenMP in Qt on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575428/how-to-compile-with-openmp-in-qt-on-macos)

adding the following to my .pro file:

```
win32: {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
}

unix:!macx {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp
}

macx: {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -lomp -I/usr/local/include
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lomp
    LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib
}
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
Compiler feature detection failure!
The command "/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -fopenmp -std=gnu++11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fPIC -x c++ -E -v - -target x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0" terminated with exit code 1.
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

As far as I understand this message I have something missing on my system but I can't figure out what

Answer (score 2):

I have found the reason.

Qt creator looks for flags in `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` and if `-fopenmp` is found it automatically uses it when performing the compiler feature detection, which fails because it's missing the 
`-Xpreprocessor` part.

The trick is to add the flags as a whole string, like this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything missing. I met this notice after updating Xcode and QtCreator some time ago.
Someone reports that simply Xcode no longer supports OpenMP.. which is possible even if I don't know why.
Doing a quick test, with a check on basic features like **omp_get/set_max_threads** and **omp parallel**, I see that OpenMP is working properly anyway.
The only real drawback, however, is that QtCreator can no longer find the standard template library includes. So for example #include  is not resolved correctly and autocompletion doesn't work.
I don't know why, but I checked it out on two different macs.
Currently I'm using Clang 10 (installed by HomeBrew) to bypass this limit.

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator on Win7 SP1 x64, and Clang was going clang and crashing on me too.  I just installed Qt Creator within the last week, and I got vers. 8.  I installed vers. 10 into the same dir, which I had already cleaned out, and clang quit crashing every time I started Qt Creator.